# Can't install google plugin for eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to install google plugin on eclipse indigo, i found an error..an error message is like this

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
  Software currently installed: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.2.1259578 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.2.1259578)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.2.1259578]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826].
```

Help me Please..thanks for your Attention

Comment: Uninstall 22.3.0 and then install 23.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You could try uninstalling the Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 and then installing Google Plugin for Eclipse again.